# Rails 3.2 + Ruby 1.9.3, created_at returns with wrong timezone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, timezone

I upgraded to Rails 3.2 and Ruby 1.9.3 and I get a very strange behavior

I have a Model called Entry. when a new Entry is created it get inserted into the DB with the current date and time.

But when I run `Entry.find_by_id(THE_ENTRY_ID).created_at` I get the "correct" created at datetime but In a different TimeZone for example:
in the db:

> 2013-03-24 00:05:29

while in the Rails console and in the application:

> Sat, 23 Mar 2013 20:05:29 EDT -04:00

Why is it suddenly returning the wrong time zone?

Answer (score 3):

OK after reading the DOCS and seeing this rails casts:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/106-time-zones-revised

everything is now clear.

```
config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

this setting is the actual setting that's in charged of converting all time objects to this current time zone. that is way i saw it as -4

this setting:

```
config.active_record.default_timezone
```

is the one that decides on how to save the time in the DB, but... it only gets 2 possible values: :local and :UTC and the default is :UTC

when i used the rails console to see my entry the time presented is after the conversion to 'Eastern Time' , in order to see the actual date stored in the DB use:

```
created_at_before_type_cast
```

which returned the UTC time as it is the default

and the reason i thought that in the DB its stored in my time zone +2
is because i used MySQL Workbench and its GUI just showed me the datetime values in my local machine time.

summary:

the setting that actually matters:

```
config.time_zone
```

it works just fine.
going through the DOCS is important

Answer (score 1):

Check the configuration in the `application.rb`. If no timezone is set, rails will take the default timezone of your operating system. To fix that, set UTC as the timezone.

Comment: in my application.rb i had: config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
and i added: config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)' but i still have the same problem... it appears that when it is saved its my timezone (+2) and when I fetch it its -4

Comment: Have you tried the [localization helper](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats) in your views? Not sure if it's available in rails console, but it's aliased to I18n#l, or just l in your views. That said, I don't know why it would be -4 when fetched.